Published Kotlin Multiplatform project's child module fetch url doesn't match pom file
I have a KMP library project that has nested/child library modules, all of which I have published to a private remote Maven repository using the maven-publish gradle plugin. The private repository information is added to the Library project via maven-publish.
:library
  :feature
  :...

When my separate Android project targets the KMP Library there are issues resolving the child modules; AndroidStudio can easily find the top level Library but attempts to find the child dependencies of my Library and fails to download them. One of the URL patterns it tries is the private repository domain, but the path to the module it's trying to use is incorrect. All of the child modules have this problem.
Inspecting the pom file of the top-level dependency (downloaded from Maven) I can see the following dependencies declared (where the parent module is called library and the child dependency module is called feature):
 <project ...>
  <groupId>com.example.library</groupId>
  <artifactId>library-android</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.2</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.library.feature</groupId>
      <artifactId>feature-android</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
 </project>

When I attempt to build my Android project adding com.example.library as a dependency, Android studio looks to resolve com.example.library.feature here:
https://<private-maven-domain>/<project-path>/com/example/library/feature/feature/0.1.2/feature-0.1.2.pom
This fails, because the actual location of the hosted module is:
https://<private-maven-domain>/<project-path>/com/example/feature/feature-android/0.1.2/feature-android-0.1.2.pom
My best guess is for some reason the -android portion of the artifactId is being dropped when AndroidStudio uses the Library pom to build a lookup URL.
I have not been able to find any explanation for how either AndroidStudio dependency resolution (how the download urls are built), or the maven-publish plugin work (to see if my project set up is either not supported, or there is a genuine bug).
Thank you for any help/insights. Happy to update any part of the question to improve clarity.
